# Binding User Control Property with another Property

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-8, windows-store-apps

In my **Windows Store Application** I want to bind a Property in a user control with another Property in logical class

the User Control "Card_UC.xaml.cs" contains this Property:

```
public string Card_ID
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(Card_ID_Property); }
    set { SetValue(Card_ID_Property, value); }
}

public DependencyProperty Card_ID_Property = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Card_ID", 
        typeof(string), 
        typeof(Card_UC), 
        new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

and in my logical class "Card_Data.cs":

```
public string Card_ID { get; set; }
```

In Main Page I want to make a Grid of this Cards using data binding like this

```
<GridView
    x:Name="UI_GView_Cards"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:CardControl
                x:Name="UC_Card"
                CardPressed="CardControl_CardPressed"
                ID="{Binding Path=Card_ID, ElementName=Card_UC, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

all the other Properties binding in the "Card_UC.xaml" working except **Card_ID**

the problem now is that the application crashes every time I access the ID Property using

```
return (string)GetValue(Card_ID_Property);
```

Error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

---

**Problem Fixed:**

the problem in this line:

```
ID="{Binding Path=Card_ID, ElementName=Card_UC, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

changed to:

```
ID="{Binding Card_ID}"
```

---

Edit:

- Fixed "Copy/Paste" mistake.
- Re-Format the question.

Comment: assing some default value to destination property and see if works.

Comment: @Jodha: I assigned a value to it in the User control Constructor Like this:
Card_ID = "0";
and as unexpected the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" still exist.
any Ideas ??

Comment: @Jodha: thanks a lot for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a cut and paste error:

```
public string Card_ID
{
   get { return (string)GetValue(UCAppsProperty); }
   set { SetValue(UCAppsProperty, value); }
}
```

to:

```
public string Card_ID
{
   get { return (string)GetValue(Card_ID_Property); }
   set { SetValue(Card_ID_Property, value); }
}
```

Comment: Ah could you update the question to include exactly what you have now, rather than the old non-dp version, and show the Problem type also?

Comment: the Question Updated, and I really don't know what causes that problem.

Comment: Problem fixed,
Thanks a lot for you attention and comments!